# If a person goes against the law, should I report him?

Tags: adab, criminal

The holy and noble Qur'an tell us that we should combat injustice, corruption, etc, but we should also be just.

Let's say that there's someone who goes against law to gain more money (even if it's a simple law and the person is kind of nice).  Should I report him to the authorities?  When should I be harsh and when to be forgiving?

What is better: that I forgive him or that I report him?   He will lose his job and he will have to work for 2 years without a salary if I do that.

Answer (score 2):

Well some people say that one has to abide by the rules of law of that region where he is living as long as they don't oppose the basic Islamic laws.

The very basic laws include not telling lies, not stealing, not deceiving other people, not hurting others, not performing deeds which might bring loss to others etc.

You forgive other people when they hurt you. That is what [Qur'an 42:37-43](http://quran.com/42/37-43)
say. But we don't get to forgive people who break the laws primarily set by Islam (like the fore mentioned) and the ones set by that region or organization. Because when you(your friend) join the organization, you might have also signed the agreement stating that he/she is going to abide by the rules set forth by that org. So, it makes it a must for him/her to abide by the rules if he/she has made such an agreement and not break them.

Beyond which are not listed in the agreement and doing things which don't break the basic Islamic law is fine.

May the creator guide us all.